# x axis labels in ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

If the number of panels in the last row is different to the rows above, the x-axis labels are missing in a facet plot with ggplot2. How can I add these?

For example:

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, colour=color))
d + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ clarity, ncol=5)
```

gives:

[image]

where the carat labels are missing for columns 4 and 5.

Comment: Add `, scales = "free"` to your `facet_wrap`

Comment: Just so you know, if I recall correctly, there was a time when it would plot the "extra" x axes floating off in space as you described and that behavior was removed intentionally because folks didn't like it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297155/add-floating-axis-labels-in-facet-wrap-plot) question may be helpful.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: This adds labels to each panel, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @joran: That's interesting. To me it would be great to have it back as an option.

Comment: @tonytonov: Thanks for pointing to this question! Version 1 in the link did the trick!

Comment: You are welcome! You may now either post your solution and mark it as accepted, or leave the question as it is. In the latter case it is likely to be closed as a duplicate after a while.