# How to add missing x-axis in multi faceted plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe called `cpp`. I have plotted the figure below which is missing X-axis in two of the plots in the right. How can I put the x-axis for these two plots? Additionally, I would also like to increase the size of each box,so the lines would not touch the margin on the right.

```
ggplot(cpp, aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, group = key.related.sheet, color = cutoff)) +
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~cutoff) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1607

Comment: You might get it to work by installing one of the development branches with `devtools::install_github('thomasp85/ggplot2', ref = 'ggproto-facets')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer about the "dangling" facets: [add "floating" axis labels in facet_wrap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297155/add-floating-axis-labels-in-facet-wrap-plot/13316126#13316126)

Or as a quick workaround (if it is ok to add x axis to all facets), you can set the parameter `scales = "free_x"` of `facet_wrap`.

Regarding the second part of your question, try to set the second value of the `expand` parameter in `scale_x_continuous`, e.g.:

```
ggplot(cpp, aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, group = key.related.sheet, color = cutoff))+
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~cutoff, scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, .1))
```